# Closing PowerPoint add-in without closing PowerPoint

Tags: c#, interop, ms-office, powerpoint

I've created an add-in for powerpoint but i have a problem.

After closing the form from my add-in PowerPoint will close too.

Can i somehow just close my add-in without closing PowerPoint?

The same add-in is working with OneNote without problems. (changed the code so it works with powerpoint)

Edit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Extensibility;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Camera_PP
{
    [GuidAttribute("38E95838-DAB6-4C56-BFF5-F55FFDD40028"),ProgId("Camera_PP.Class1")]
    public class Class1 : IDTExtensibility2,IRibbonExtensibility
    {



        public string GetCustomUI(string RibbonID)
        {
            return Properties.Resources.ribbon;
        }

        public void OnAddInsUpdate(ref Array custom)
        {

        }

        public void OnBeginShutdown(ref Array custom)
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        }

        public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref System.Array custom)
        {

        }

        public void OnDisconnection(ext_DisconnectMode RemoveMode, ref Array custom)
        {


            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

        public void OnStartupComplete(ref Array custom)
        {

        }
        public void showKamera(IRibbonControl control)
        {
            kamera kamera = new kamera();
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(kamera);


        }
        public IStream GetImage(string imageName)
        {
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            Properties.Resources.icon_157351_640.Save(mem, ImageFormat.Png);
            return new CCOMStreamWrapper(mem);
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the code where i'm calling my application from.
If i close the kamera form PowerPoint will close too.

Everything works without problems if i use a vsto template in VS.

Comment: Edit your post and include the relevant code, please.

Comment: Hey Steve,  the code is working. I made a new add-in with a vsto template and it is working without problems. I didn't use a template for my OneNote addin and i though i can use the same method for PowerPoint. I'll add the code where i'm opening my form to my post.